# How to have a pure HTML (from index.html) directory in a cakePhP site?

Tags: html, cakephp

I have a cakePhP site all set up.  It has its "webroot" directory and some sub-directories that each have their own "app" directory.  They all work fine.  Now I want to set up a sub-directory that runs from just an "index.html" file, no "app" directory or cakePhP directory structure with a Controller file etc.  It would be a pure HTML sub-directory.

If I just add a subdirectory containing just an "index.html" file (no ".htaccess" file in it) I get a cakePhP error saying the controller file for that directory is missing.

The ".htaccess" file of the overall "webroot" directory looks like this.  I cannot change that ".htaccess" file because the other sub-directories depend on those rules.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Does anyone know what I need to do e.g. set up a local .htaccess file in my sub-directory to make my sub-directory work with just HTML?

Answer (score 2):

Inside webroot/html folder create some html files, index.html, ...

test http://somesite.com/html/index.html

Comment: Maybe we're on different cakephp's version. I'm with 2.10

Comment: Default, without routing works in all cakephp versions, like access css, img, js @RicardoVigatti

Comment: Yep, you're right. Its working now, I should be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to hard code your sub-directory as the the first RewriteRule. Let's say your regular HTML sub directory is called "html".

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    /html$ app/webroot/html    [L]
   RewriteRule    /html/(.*) app/webroot/html/$1    [L]
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This way it will check if you are trying to access the sub directory before the rules for Cake are checked. I haven't tested this, but give it a try.

Comment: Changing webroot's .htaccess file would require a fair amount of re-testing and validation on my other sub-directories.  Do you think there may be a way to get that same effect by putting some overriding rules in a local .htaccess file within my html directory?

Comment: The problem is that webroot's .htaccess would get checked first, and its rewrite would happen, so you would never make it into the html directory.